# A good way to create unique entity keys in Python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, key, md5

Suppose I have an entity in my datastore that I know it can have a unique `key_name`  deriving from a combination of it's properties:

Example:

```
class Render(db.Model):

    #Math props
    x_size = db.IntegerProperty()
    y_size = db.IntegerProperty()
    center_axis_x = db.FloatProperty()
    center_axis_y = db.FloatProperty()
    center_axis_z = db.FloatProperty()
    iterations = db.IntegerProperty()
```

I am sure that there can be no other entity with the exact same properties so in order to create the unique key I user so far:

```
render_key=hashlib.md5(str(properties.x_size) +
                                str(properties.y_size) +
                                str(properties.iterations) +
                                str(properties.center_axis_x) +
                                str(properties.center_axis_y) +
                                str(properties.center_axis_z)
                                ).hexdigest()
```

The hexdigest let's me make the key url-safe and user friendly but I believe it might need discussion as well.

So to the question. In the above scenario or an altered version of that, are there any other better ways to achieve the same result? It doesn't need to be backward compatible. So even if the final key differs from the one generated by my method it's not a problem.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you let the database handle the generation of unique keys for you?

Comment: @J.Gonzalez Because I need to use get_or_insert that requires the key to be known for something new.

Comment: A hash seems fine, but you should consider using `str.join` instead of the `+` concatenation.

Comment: If you want to avoid the - relatively unlikely chance (if using SHA-256 you can basically disregard it) - of a hash collision, you could also just use a base64 encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overall your plan is good, except that md5 doesn't guarantee that you won't have collisions (although it's very unlikely).  You can make collisions even more unlikely by using SHA-256 instead, or just don't hash it and you're good to go.

Depends on whether you're ok with living with the very rare case that a collision does occur and you overwrite the wrong entity.

Comment: If I don't hash them, then will it be safe as an str representation of multiple types? 
Like joining many types into a string sounds ok but does it hide any dark paths?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by multiple types.  You're just going to have a string of numbers.  I can see two things to be careful about.  1: when you stick 2 integers together, you end up with another integer, and you don't know where one ends and the other begins, you need to work around that, either a fixed number of digits or add a delimiter between fields.  Secondly with floats, you need to be careful with the # of decimal places that show up.